# Creating Index in Doctrine2 / Symfony2 Throws Semantical Error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a simple index to a table in Doctrine2 / Symfony2 using annotations and I'm getting the following error:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Index" in class {My\Namespaces\Here} was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

I can't find in any documentation what namespace I'm supposed to "use" to add the Index functionality. Here's my annotation:

```
@ORM\Table(indexes={@Index(name="email_address_idx", columns={"email_address"})})
```

And here are the namespaces I'm already using:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

What namespace do I need to use to add this functionality?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Looks like you need:

```
@ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="email_address_idx", columns={"email_address"})})
```

Comment: How to add indexes on multiple columns using this approach?

Comment: What if I set the `unique` attribute on a column ? Will the SGBD automaticaly set some index on the target table column ?

Comment: @jitendra : simply add more column names in the `column` list
e.g.: `@ORM\Table(indexes={@ORM\Index(name="email_address_idx", columns={"email_address", "username"})})`

Answer (score 17):

You can use the following to solve the issue:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Index;
```